# how to toggle clicked switch instead of all switches in react mui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

this is my state in parent component

```
  const [feedbackType, setFeedbackType] = useState({
    manual: true,
    auto: false,
  });
```

i am passing this state as a props to child component.
in child component i have this code

```
const handleFeedbackChange = type => {
    setFeedbackType(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      manual: type === 'manual',
      auto: type === 'auto',
    }));
  };

    <div>
          <Switch
            checked={feedbackType.manual}
            onChange={() => handleFeedbackChange('manual')}
            name="manual-feedback"
            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Manual feedback' }}
            color="primary"
          />
          <label htmlFor="manual-feedback">Manual Feedback</label>

          <Switch
            checked={feedbackType.auto}
            onChange={() => {handleFeedbackChange('auto')}
            name="auto-feedback"
            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Auto feedback' }}
            color="primary"
          />
          <label htmlFor="auto-feedback">Auto Feedback</label>
        </div>
```

my issue is i am running map on child component so if i have multiple data then there will be multiple switches. so whenever i try to turn on and off first switch then if effect on other switch as well.
can someone improve the logic according to this?
i try to implement something like passing id as a argument to function then receiving it as a parameter and make logic according to it.but i unable to do this.
[image]

Comment: It's unclear what  your goal with this UI is. If manual and auto are mutually exclusive, why are there two separate switches to control them?

Comment: "I'm displaying different data based on the states of the manual and auto switches. My problem arises when I'm mapping over a child component. Let's say I have three objects in my data. As a result, my UI will have switches displayed like this:

Manual feedback switch 1, Auto feedback switch 1
Manual feedback switch 2, Auto feedback switch 2
Manual feedback switch 3, Auto feedback switch 3

Comment: The issue occurs when I try to turn on the auto feedback switch 1. It ends up turning on all the other auto feedback switches, such as auto feedback switch 2 and auto feedback switch 3. However, I only want auto feedback switch 1 to be turned on."

Comment: Try adding a unique `key` prop to each Switch component.

Comment: Can u give me sample code?
i already have unique key but how to use it?

Comment: i did this 
onChange={() => handleFeedbackChange('manual')}
            name={`manual-feedback${submittedAssignmentData.id}`}

 onChange={() => {
              handleFeedbackChange('auto')}
            name={`auto-feedback${submittedAssignmentData.id}`}

but this is not working

Answer (score 1):

you should move your `useState` inside the child component so that when you map throw the data, react would create a specific state for each rendered component, right now you are using one useState hook for all:

parent component:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    
    const data = // your data

    return (
        data.map((item, index) => <ChildComponent key={index} item={item} />)
    )
}
```

and you should change the `handleFeedbackChange` function like the code example bellow

child component:

```
const ChildComponent = ({ item }) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        manual: true,
        auto: false,
    })

    const handleFeedbackChange = type => {\
        if(type === 'manual'){
           setState(prevState => ({
             ...prevState,
             manual: true,
           }));
        } else {
           setState(prevState => ({
             ...prevState,
             auto: true,
           }));
        }
    };

    return (
        <Switch
            checked={state.manual}
            onChange={() => handleFeedbackChange('manual')}
        />
        <Switch
            checked={state.auto}
            onChange={() => handleFeedbackChange('auto')}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: before my state was also inside child component. This is also not working

Comment: it would work try the code above one more time

Comment: "I can pass the id as a prop to the child component and then use it as an argument for the handleFeedbackChange function. However, I have been unsuccessful in implementing this logic correctly. I have attempted to pass the id as a prop and receive it in the handleFeedbackChange function, but my logic is incorrect."

Comment: i edited the answer try this and it would work :)

Comment: Your old answer is correct. Before i was doing like this but intentionally i did current code. Anyway thanks and will let you know and i will accept your previous answer

Comment: Hey  Mohammad Hussein do you know how to do this with redux-saga? Keeping usestate inside child component making switches unique. But my issue is i need this switch state in somewhere component in depth.so i did this using redux saga but i am facing same issue.